# How to extend prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can we do that? Like

```
example.add();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should pass the variable and the comparison value.

```js
var a = 2;
function validate(variable, conditional) {
  if (variable != conditional) return conditional
}; 

a = validate(a, 3)
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the new value instead of the result of the comparison so that you'll be able to change the value of a to the new value.

```js
const validate = (newVal) =>
  a === newVal ? a : a = newVal

var a = 2;
validate(3); //It turns "a" into 3;
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

`a == 3` is evaluated *in place* and the result is passed to the function (so the function knowns nothing about the expression).

Even if that wasn't the case, variables are passed by value, so it wouldn't know anything about `a` either.